# Is there a Google Script command to reload a Google Sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I have written a Google script that puts the sheets (i.e., tabs) in a Google Spreadsheet in alpha order.

The problem is that the horizontal list of tabs at the bottom of the spreadsheet page do not display (left to right) in alpha order.

The tab that started out as the "firstSheet" will generally end up after the script has run somewhere in the middle of "the pack" and the alphabetization will start from there and "wrap around" until the last tab in the alpha list is just before it. (I say "generally" because sometimes it does show up all the way to the left—depending on where it started out.)

I should also mention that the script is bound to a spreadsheet and is triggered by the user as a Custom menu item.

The basic script I am using comes hat tip @Serge-insas ([Method "moveActiveSheet" doesn't work as expected in Google Apps Script (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667862/method-moveactivesheet-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-google-apps-script-javascr)). And the only real modification I have made to that script is to add a line to display the first alpha tab at the end of the process.

I have also added a sidebar to the whole affair as a workaround to the "wrapping" problem mentioned above as I have discovered that there is a right-click "Reload" option for sidebars and it reloads the spreadsheet and that reload displays the tabs in the proper alpha order from left to right.

## Menu Script

```
function onOpen() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Sort Sheets', 'sortSheets')
      .addToUi();
```

## function

```
function sortSheets () {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setTitle('Read Me')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var firstSheet = sheets[0].getName();
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var sheetNameArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {     
      sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
    }
  var sheetNameArray = sheetNameArray.sort(); 
  for(var s=0 ; s < numSheets ; s++){    
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray [s]));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(50);
    ss.moveActiveSheet(numSheets);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(50);
  }
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(firstSheet));
}
```

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
      <center><font color = red>IMPORTANT<br><br> 
    Once the routine has run (i.e., the tabs stop moving around) and you see the "saved" notification at the top of the page...<br><br>
     
     Right click anywhere in this sidebar. Then select the "reload" menu item to reset sheet tabs in alpha order.</center></font> <br> <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

So my question is: is there a way to make that reload happen other than the sidebar? I.e., is there some command I can use on my script rather than having to use the rather convoluted sidebar approach?  The fact that there is a reload function in a sidebar makes me hope for a way programmatically to get at it, though searching Google GAS documentation, I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like your code should work. Not sure why it isn't. However, this is a simpler way to order the sheets.

```
function sortSheets()
{
  // get the current spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // get an array of sheets
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();

  // sort the array by sheet name
  allSheets.sort(function(s1, s2){
    if(s1.getName().toLowerCase() < s2.getName().toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if(s1.getName().toLowerCase() > s2.getName().toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  // move the sheet into where they should be based on sorted order
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet, sheetIndex){
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    ss.moveActiveSheet(sheetIndex + 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: I am not following. Could you please post a picture? The above code will sort the horizontal tabs on the bottom in alpha order left to right.

Comment: Tried it a few more times and it seems to be working. I am going to do some more testing and if all is well, I will mark this one answered (and i thank you)!

Comment: K. The code you have should work too. Not sure the issue you're having. If it happens again can you post a picture?

Comment: I added these two lines: `var firstSheet = allSheets[0].getName();` and 
  `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(firstSheet));` to get the first sheet in the spreadsheet as the active sheet (at the end of the sort) as your code was defaulting to the last sheet in the set as the active sheet.

Comment: If you just want to make the first sheet active after moving them around you can add this at the end: `ss.setActiveSheet(allSheets[0]);`